# Generating Canal on DEM using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, dem

I want to generate a canal going from point A to B with a given slope.

The canal should be on the underlying DEM.

Is there any way to do this with the tools in ArcGIS 10 or do I have to do it manually?

I also have Qgis, Globalmapper and BricsCAD (with GeoTools) available if that helps in any way.

---

It's about an irrigation canal. We start at a dam with a given elevation. Now we go along the hill with a constant slope of let's say 0.1% downhill up to my endpoint (or end area). So eventually the endpoint is defined by the slope too. However I could figure out where the end point is and just linearly interpolate in between the two points then. The canal should be on the surface of the DEM.

We're talking about a canal on a hillside / in a valley so there is plenty of natural slope. The canal goes along the hillside from the start to the end of the valley. Basically following the contour lines but slightly sloping downwards in order to have some flow.

Comment: I can think of a possibility using Spatial Analyst tools. Do you have SA? Also, is the canal a constant slope along the length?

Comment: For example, between point A and B, you want to add a canal of depth X?  Wouldn't the canal be subject to the slope of the surrounding landscape, or how do you want to address that?

Comment: Is the slope determined by the elevation difference between the two points (i.e. one is uphill and the other down), and the starting and ending elevations are tied to the ground surface at the points less some canal depth? If this is the case, is your canal possibly above ground level in places to maintain the slope? I wish I had a few more votes left today to upvote this question ;)

Comment: Also, are you attempting to model the canal water surface or canal bottom, to be filled with accumulated flow (i.e. virtual water)?

Comment: Ok, some clarification. It's about an irrigation canal. We start at a dam with a given elevation. Now we go along the hill with a constant slope of let's say 0.1% downhill up to my endpoint (or end area). So eventually the endpoint is defined by the slope too. However I could figure out where the end point is and just linearly interpolate in between the two points then. The canal should be on the surface of the DEM. I have the SA. Tried it with the Path tool but cant get a result that makes sense.

Comment: @st3435 So is it that there is a constant slope or a minimum slope? As Aaron points out, most irrigation canals would have slopes that are constrained by the overlying landscape.

Comment: @phloem It's just the centerline for the canal projected on the terrain surface - filling with water etc. is not happening at this point (unless necessary for this GIS task...)

Comment: @WhiteboxDev For now a constant slope. Basically I am thinking of a polyline with a constant slope that is then put on the "right place" on the DEM (if that makes sense?). The canal is on the side of a hill/valley so there is "plenty of DEM slope to put it on".

Comment: I am still a bit confused.  Are you looking to "burn" a canal of a certain depth into a DEM based on a polygon?

Comment: @Aaron: I'll try to explain: If I had a canal with 0% slope it would be along a contour line. So now with 0.1% slope it slowly goes from one contour line to the next one. I don't need the exact cross section or something in arcgis - I just need a line along which the canal will later go (the exact design will be done in AutoCAD at a later stage). Think of a centerline like you would have if you show a road on a map. So what I'm looking to work on is a polyline.

Comment: With no answers in nearly two years I think you need to consider heavily revising your question to try and make what you are asking clear and focussed on a single software product that you want most to try and solve it with.